# What are the effects of storing drinking water in a copper container?

Tags: water, metal, water-treatment

I recently learned that Ayurveda recommends storing drinking water in copper containers for positive health benefits.

Upon my simple experimentation, I've noticed the following effects:

**Water Type** : activated carbon filtered drinking water

**Duration of storage**: 8 hours

The taste of the water changed, it tasted more metallic. I think this is because of the increase of dissolved copper in the water.

If I'm drinking 4-5 liters of water per day, would that be still under the safe limit of 2 mg/day? [ref 2](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/dwq/chemicals/copper.pdf) Note: I don't have any apparatus to measure the copper content in the water.

I've researched a bit and found that it does have some positive effects on killing some microbes such as bacteria [ref 1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3312355/). Note: I'm not able to deduce any conclusion about the increase in copper content from this paper even though the author said it is "within the permissible limits."

I would like to know more about the studies related to this claim and I'm really interested to know about the side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state, copper storage containers have long been used to prevent growth of pathogens in potable water.

As for the [danger of copper toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_toxicity), it depends on the pH and water temperature. [Between pH 8 and 11, about 1 ppm of copper dissolves](http://www.rhomarwater.com/assets/pdf/literature/Copper%20Solubility%20with%20pH.PDF), so if you're consuming ~5 l/day or about 5,000 g/day of water, **and if the water has had sufficient time to become saturated**, then you'd get ~5 mg/day of copper, exceeding suggested safe limits for long-term exposure.

That said, I think that, *if* the water pH is between 8 and 11, and *if* it is refrigerated (e.g. 4 C), and *if* it has been standing quiescently for no more than eight hours, it would *not* have time to be saturated with copper, so it *probably* would be safe to drink if that were the only source of copper in your diet.

Given all those mealy-mouthed *caveats*, then, you might at least check the pH of the tap water, and use a different container if it's acid. You would not want to be like the [drinkers from Yudono spring](https://www.damninteresting.com/sokushinbutsu-the-ancient-buddhist-mummies-of-japan/), unless you're *really* into Heavy Metal.